# What is the macro for std::string/std::wstring in vc++?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

According to MSDN:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff381407%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

You can write TCHAR for char or wchar_t depend on compiler MACRO UNICODE

Is there a similar symbol for std::string and std::wstring?

Thanks!

(My VC++ version is 2013)

Comment: The TCHAR and UNICODE macros are part of the Windows API, which is distinct from the C++ runtime library APIs.  That's why there isn't already one.  Visual C++ does provide some TCHAR-like functionality in the C runtime library, but that triggers off `_UNICODE` (note the leading underscore).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could define it yourself:

```
typedef basic_string<TCHAR, char_traits<TCHAR>, allocator<TCHAR> >  tstring;
```

Comment: Thanks, it shall be written in this way in my environment: typedef std::basic_string<TCHAR, std::char_traits<TCHAR>, std::allocator<TCHAR> > tstring;

Answer (score 1):

I did not find one. I wrote one myself in my code like this -

```
#ifdef UNICODE
  #define tstring std::wstring
#else
  #define tstring std::string
#endif
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also tweak a bit by adding the namespace in your stdafx.h

```
namespace std {
    typedef basic_string<TCHAR, char_traits<TCHAR>, allocator<TCHAR> >  tstring;
}
```